# Запятая в конце предложения, обособленного тире

Tags: запятые, тире

Такие примеры: 
1. «Мне сказали, что она в порядке — и меня это не сказать, что утешило(,) — и что мне не стоит волноваться». 
Мои мысли. Мне кажется, там должна стоять запятая, потому что перед обособленным предложением сложное. Но я не уверена. (Извиняюсь за сумбурность — своими словами объясняю.)
2. «Здание было красивым — я хотел рассмотреть его получше(,) — и к тому же нарядным». 
А здесь я не уверена. 
Периодически приходится использовать такой способ выделения нужной информации, поэтому интересно мнение, так сказать, экспертов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложение 1. ***Мне сказали, что она в порядке — и меня это не сказать, что утешило(,) — и что мне не стоит волноваться***.

Определяем грамматику

1) В предложении есть вставная конструкция, обособленная двумя тире (выражает чувства автора).

2) Предложение без вставки: *Мне сказали, что она в порядке и что мне не стоит волноваться.* Запятой нет в СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными (одиночный союз И).

3) Анализ вставной конструкции:

*И меня это не сказать что утешило*.
Запятая не ставится ввиду инверсии. Сравнить (прямой порядок слов): *Не сказать, что меня это утешило.* Правило Розенталя: Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга . Он уже месяц как вернулся с юга — запятая перед союзом как «оторвала» бы сказуемое от подлежащего.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Решение:

Заданное предложение оформляется следующим образом: ***Мне сказали, что она в порядке — и меня это не сказать что утешило — и что мне не стоит волноваться.***

При отсутствии запятых на месте вставки и в самой вставке для обособления используются только тире.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Вариант стилистической правки: ***Мне сообщили, что она в порядке — меня это не сказать что утешило — и что не стоит волноваться.***

Вариант без инверсии: ***Мне сообщили, что она в порядке — не сказать, что меня это утешило, — и что не стоит волноваться***. Запятая перед вторым тире закрывает придаточное внутри вставки.

Предложение 2. ***Здание было красивым — я хотел рассмотреть его получше — и к тому же нарядным.***

Определяем грамматику

1) В предложении есть вставная конструкция, обособленная двумя тире (попутное замечание автора).

2) Предложение без вставки: *Здание было красивым и к тому же нарядным.* Запятой нет (однородные сказуемые, одиночный союз И).

Решение:

Заданное предложение оформляется следующим образом: ***Здание было красивым — я хотел рассмотреть его получше — и к тому же нарядным.*** При отсутствии запятых на месте вставки и в самой вставке для обособления используются только тире.

Вариант стилистической правки: ***Здание было красивым — я хотел рассмотреть его получше — и к тому же выглядело необычно.***

Здесь общая тема – это интерес к зданию (отсюда сочетание *и к тому же*, а прилагательные *красивый, нарядный* однородны по смыслу.

Comment: Благодарю за подробности! Давно уже хотела разобраться. :)